# Send virtual MIDI events from PortMIDI

Tags: virtual, midi

I have portMidi on win 8 and I want to create a virtual keyboard that sends midi events to Fruity Loops Studio, but when I try to select a device from the Midi Input I can't find any device. Can you help me link these two softwares?

Answer (score 1):

Windows has no built-in mechanism to connect multiple MIDI applications together; all MIDI ports must be implemented by some driver.

You would have to install a driver for a virtual MIDI port/cable.